# Make Android Studio autopop up not change constrast

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, pressing the up an down arrows will change the contrast of the autopopup bar.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

This also occurs in the default themes. Is there anyway to make the contrast start in the after position, even without pressing any arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is dimmed to indicate that there is no default selection for completion. It depends on context and in some cases the first entry will be selected automatically, while in the other cases you need to select the completion varian with the arrow keys first.

To get the pre-selection work automatically in IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio enable the **Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys** option:

[image: Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys]

In some other cases it may be also necessary to add

`-Dide.completion.lookup.element.preselect.depends.on.context=false`

in `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options** and restart the IDE.

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193090.

Comment: This does not appear to fix it. Note: in IntelliJ, the popup is already in the after stage by default.